# How to increase printers buffer while printing via command line?

Tags: printing

I have a Epson Stylus P50 usb printer and i need to print many copies (50~100) of some .prn files created via windows.

I cannot alter/convert those files; They need to be printed exactly as they are.

I installed the printer with cups and gutenprint drivers for epson R285 (there is not much difference between the 2 printer models).

My problem is that printing the prn with

```
lp -d printer_name -n 100 /path/to/file.prn
```

or

```
lpr -P printer_name -# 100 /path/to/file.prn
```

does not work as expected; Randomly the printer stops, in CUPS I got the error `Unable to write 9640 bytes on printer_name` and the jobs queue happens to be cleared automatically.

Sometimes, the printer prints 1~2 copies before stopping, but often it stops with the first copy.

I guess the problem is that Ubuntu expects the printer buffer is bigger than it actually is... but I really do not know.

So, is there a way to increase the printer buffer, or to lower the buffer that Ubuntu expects the printer to have?

**Edit**: the error happens even giving just 1 copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/427653) might be relevant to your case, unfortunately it does not provide a solution.

If you're affected by that bug you should mark the bug as affecting you (upper left side) and subscribe to the bug.

Comment: Seem to be the same problem